# Vim project plugin \R not refreshing new directories created

Tags: vim, plugins, text-editors

I'm using the vim project plugin to manage a project, and whenever a new file goes in I need to use \R to refresh the project tree. This is fine, but I recently created a new directory in the tree, and \R doesn't update it and put it into the project.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `**/*` as the `filter` pattern as the default pattern is `*` which does not descend into directories. See `:he glob()` and `:he wildcards` for details.